# Math.random returning same value when console logged javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, if-statement

here is my code

```
// import user input prompt 
var inquirer = require('inquirer');
var emptyFamArray = [];

// ask the user how many relatives do they have

const getQuestions = () => {
    inquirer.prompt([
      {
        name: "relatives_names",
        type: 'input',
        message: "Please input family first names seperated by a space. only 1-10 family members please!",
        
    },
    ]).then((answers => {
        // console.log(answers)
        let test1 = JSON.stringify(answers.relatives_names).split(' ');
        // console.log(test1);
       
        let randomArrayName = test1[Math.floor(test1.length * Math.random())]
        let randomArrayNameTwo = test1[Math.floor(test1.length * Math.random())]
        console.log(randomArrayName)
    
  
        if(test1.length > 10){
            console.log('to many names please input 10 or less')
        } else if (test1.length == 9){

           
            console.log(randomArrayName + " Gets " + randomArrayNameTwo + " for christmas pickings!");
        
         
        }else if (test1.length == 5){
            console.log(randomArrayName + " Gets " + randomArrayNameTwo + " for christmas pickings!");
            console.log(randomArrayName + " Gets " + randomArrayNameTwo + " for christmas pickings!");
            console.log(randomArrayName + " Gets " + randomArrayNameTwo + " for christmas pickings!");
            console.log(randomArrayName + " Gets " + randomArrayNameTwo + " for christmas pickings!");
            console.log(randomArrayName + " Gets " + randomArrayNameTwo + " for christmas pickings!");
```

when it console logs it does randomise the names but it only returns the same value over and over

example

```
kylee Gets gerald for christmas pickings!
kylee Gets gerald for christmas pickings!
kylee Gets gerald for christmas pickings!
```

how would I fix this? im stuck and not entirly sure how to make the variables random everytime when logged

Thanks

Comment: You reference `randomArrayName` and `randomArrayNameTwo` several times but set these bindings only once. Why do you expect them to be different?

Answer (score 0):

When you are printing to the console the random selection have already happened and it happens only ones **before** you print out the names.
To make it select a random name each time , convert the selection to a function which you will call every time you want to print to console. For example:

```
var selectRandomName = function(names) {
 return names[Math.floor(names.length * Math.random())]
}

console.log(selectRandomName(names) + " GETS " + selectRandomName(names) + " for Christmas pickings!");
```

Obviously this is oversimplified and you probably should also prevent selection of the same name twice and other similar cases, but this is out of the scope of current question. I assume this is some sort of exercise, as in real world application you should use some readily available matching libraries.